Optimizar busqueda del SID del administrador local en registro
Estoy realizando un script para la modificación del registro de usuarios específicos de mi dominio en el que incluyo también el administrador local pero su SID es único por equipo/pc y aquí es donde tengo el problema, he realizado primero un filtro de los usuarios para ver si existen en el equipo y luego busco el SID del administrador pero en cuanto paso los datos a los txts y le hago buscar el patrón para que coincida con la clave del administrador tarda muchísimo estilo 10 min en que me salte al siguiente paso, crear nuevas claves. ¿Como podría optimizar esta operación y que tarde menos tiempo en encontrar la clave del administrador? ¿O como podría buscar el SID del administrador de otra forma que no tarde tanto?
$ruta_registro = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\"
Set-Location $ruta_registro

Get-ChildItem | Format-List | Out-File "C:\InforH\PRUREG.txt" -Force
#FILTRO PARA PODER SACAR EL SID A TXTS
$saligci = Get-Content "C:\InforH\PRUREG.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -like "PSChildName*" }
Set-Content -Path "C:\InforH\busq500.txt" -Value $saligci
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

$sali500 = Get-Content "C:\InforH\busq500.txt"
#ACUERDATE DE LA DOCUMENTACION DE REGEX OJO CON EL?
$patron = "S-1-5-21-(\d+-?)+-500"
#BUSCO EL VALOR QUE COINCIDE
$ad500 = $sali500 | Select-String -Pattern $patron | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } | Select-Object -First 1


#SID de los usuarios
$USU_UR = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-404"
$USU_C = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-302"
$USU_UE = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-303"
$USU_A = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-634"
$USU_R = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-532"
$USU_S = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-304"
$USU_L = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-309"
$USU_ADMIN = "$ad500"
$USU_ALV = "S-1-5-21-x-y-z-779"

$USU_UR,$USU_C,$USU_UE,$USU_A,$USU_R,$USU_S,$USU_L,$USU_ADMIN,$USU_ALV | ForEach-Object {

$ruta_usuario_registro = Join-Path -Path $ruta_registro -ChildPath $_

#EXISTE LA CLAVE?
if (Test-Path -Path $ruta_usuario_registro) {
    Write-Host "El SID del usuario $_ EXISTE en la ruta del registro."
        $resp = Read-Host "¿Quieres seguir modificando el registro del usuario?"

    If ($resp -eq "si" -or $resp -eq "Si" -or $resp -eq "SI")
        {
            $DirectReg = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$_\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\kille\pepe\pipi"
            Set-Location $DirectReg
            $keynueva = Read-Host "Estás en la ruta del registro quieres agregar una key nueva?"
            if ($keynueva -eq "si" -or $keynueva -eq "Si" -or $keynueva -eq "SI"){
                New-ItemProperty -Path $DirectReg -Name 'CLIALV' -Value 'PRUEBA OK'
                }
            else{
                Write-Host "No se agrega una key nueva"
                }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Hasta luego, continua la busqueda de usuarios"
        }
    } 
    else {
    Write-Host "El SID del usuario $_ NO EXISTE en la ruta del registro."
}
}
Start-sleep -Seconds 3
Remove-Item "C:\InforH\PRUREG.txt"
Remove-Item "C:\InforH\busq500.txt"
Set-Location C:\Users\Administrador
```


Probá con "S-1-5-21(-\d+)+-500"

Funcionando, he pasado de 10 min a 10 seg gracias @Pollo

Te estás encontrando con un problema bastante común con expresiones regulares llamado backtracking catastrófico.
Se resuelve cambiando tu expresión
S-1-5-21-(\d+-?)+-500

por
S-1-5-21(-\d+)+-500

o incluso, si siempre son 3 grupos de dígitos en el medio (que marcaste como x-y-z), mejor usar
S-1-5-21(-\d+){3}-500


¿Por qué tarda tanto? Explicado de forma muy resumida, la expresión regular tiene tantas posibles formas de probar si coincide o no que, cuando no coincide, tiene que agotar muchísimas alternativas antes de fallar.
El problema está en (\d+-?)+, sobre todo porque el - es opcional. Esa expresión se puede convertir en \d+\d+\d+\d+\d+\d+..., y cada \d+ puede coincidir con 1 solo dígito, con 2, con 3, etc. Cuando falla al encontrar el 500, tiene que seguir intentando con otras alternativas de \d+.
Es un tema un poco complejo para ver con más detalle, pero está muy bien explicado en esta otra respuesta: ¿Cómo funciona el retroceso (Backtracking) en expresiones regulares?
